# A King's Hamiltonian Tours

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, chess, grid-deduction, primes

a) Place the numbers 1 to 25 in the cells of a 5 x 5 board in such a way that consecutive numbers occur in adjacent cells either vertically, horizontally, or diagonally, and so do cells with numbers 1 and 25. Numbers in the nine cells belonging to the board's two diagonals should all be prime.

b) Can such a placement be also achieved with numbers 2 to 37 in the cells of a 6 x 6 board? Again, numbers in the twelve cells belonging to the board's two diagonals should all be prime.

Comment: Now in The Guardian: https://www.theguardian.com/science/2021/oct/18/can-you-solve-it-hamiltonian-ingenuity-on-the-grid?fbclid=IwAR3K8EzwQwpogyIboCzQFdZdDX5PC_wfReRG3dsS1x4LBwqPuT2Y-aSKlNQ

Answer (score 12):

One solution to part A:

> ```
> 02 01 21 20 19
> 25 03 22 17 18
> 04 24 23 15 16
> 06 05 14 13 12
> 07 08 09 10 11
> ```

Answer (score 10):

Solution for the $5$x$5$ grid

> 11 12 15 16 17
>  10 13 14 19 18
>    9 24 23 22 20
>    8   5 25   3 21
>    7   6   4   1   2

Other solutions for the same grid are

> Any rotations or reflections of the above solution as the requirements don't prevent those.
>  We can also get a new solution by exchanging many pairs of numbers. For example we can swap the 14 and 15 in the above solution to get another valid solution.
>
>  11 12 14 16 17
>  10 13 15 19 18
>    9 24 23 22 20
>    8   5 25   3 21
>    7   6   4   1   2
>
>  Via computer search I found 264 solutions in total. This was done with a standard depth first search, with the constraints that no composite numbers can be placed on a diagonal line, and since there are only 9 primes, primes can only be placed along a diagonal.

For the $6$x$6$ grid I noted that

> As the numbers 2, 3, and 37 are prime, they must all lie along the diagonals. As they are 'consecutive' the 2 cannot go in a corner, as there is only one connecting square that can take a prime, whereas we need two of them.
>  This limits the starting position to
>  _ _ _ _ _ _
>  _ X _ _ X _
>  _ _ X X _ _
>  _ _ X X _ _
>  _ X _ _ X _
>  _ _ _ _ _ _

This leads to this conclusion for the $6$x$6$ grid

> Just like above rotations, reflections and some exchanges give rise to other solutions once we have one. Using the same computer search as above with the same constraints gives a total of 128 solutions. For instance
>  23 24 25 27 28 29
>  22    5    6 26 31 30
>  21    4 37    7    8 32
>  20 36    3    **2** 33    9
>  18 19 35 34 13 10
>  17 16 15 14 12 11
>
>  I didn't find any solution where the 2 was not in the centre $2$x$2$ region of the grid, but I don't have a piece of logic that eliminates that possibility.

Comment: I confirmed these solution counts of 264 and 128 via integer linear programming.

Answer (score 8):

A solution for part B:

> ```
> 11 12 14 15 16 17
> 10 13 34 35 19 18
> 09 33 02 03 36 20
> 32 08 07 37 04 21
> 30 31 26 06 05 22
> 29 28 27 25 24 23
> ```

Comment: Very nice! Did you do it by hand?

Comment: Nice job! I couldn't decide if it was possible or not. 